# How can I deliver an an encrypted file from my web server?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, encryption

I have a web application running under Windows/IIS that includes some reports via SSRS.

I would like to be able to render a report, somehow save it on the web or SSRS file system, create an encrypted version, and deliver that encrypted file to the user.

I've considered creating a zip file with a password, but not sure about how well that would work.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: What about serving it over HTTPS? If you're concerned about the security of the SSRS machine, you could create another one just to display reports or figure out how to render the SSRS markup without using SSRS (I believe it's an XML-variant if memory serves correctly... perhaps there are some XSLTs going on...)

Comment: What are you expecting the user to be able to do with this encrypted report?  Is it important that the *transit* of the file is encrypted (then I'd go with HTTPS as @Kasapo says) or is it important that it is in an encrypted container after delivery?

Comment: No, it has to be a file that the user can save and take with them, to open at a later date.

Comment: How would they decrypt this object after they have it?  Do they have/provide a password?  Something else?

Comment: @Joe - there will be a mechanism for users to get the appropriate password.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues in this - and I have to work on the assumption that the purpose of encryption is that you want to be able to distribute the report in a way that only authorized users can view it.

The simplest way of achieving this goal would be to have a login scheme, and serve the report over HTTPS. This means only those who have a log-in can download the report, and it can't be intercepted using network sniffing.

In the past, a client insisted that they wanted to avoid allowing users to download unencrypted files, because they might forward the (unencrypted) report to un-authorized users. To meet this requirement, we created a windows service which created encrypted ZIP files; we used a service because performance tests showed that creating the ZIP in the context of a web request created a serious scalability issue.

The major problem you have with this scheme is distributing decryption keys; making sure everyone has the right key for their report is a huge pain in the backside.

It also didn't prevent users from decrypting the ZIP file and emailing on the unencrypted report - but this was a clear breach of IT policies, which was a harder point to make with unencrypted reports.

Comment: There are issues, and it's more of an issue of perception of security than actual security, but I've been asked how this can be accomplished.  The output from the report needs to be saved to a file, and taken off-site, so HTTPS isn't going to help.  They are away that managing keys will be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe 7-zip or TrueCrypt?

Both require the installation of additional software however. I'm really not sure how strong ZIP file password protection is, so I would be hesitant to go that route without some research.

TrueCrypt is pretty secure, from my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a reference in your project to `http://<Server Name>/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx`. See the example included in [ReportExecutionService.Render Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render%28v=sql.105%29) for how to execute and render a report. You can then take the returned byte array from the render method and create a MemoryStream based on it.

You can perform simple compression using thing in the [System.IO.Compression Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z72378a) like this:

```
public void CompressData(Stream uncompressedSourceStream, Stream compressedDestinationStream)
{
    using (DeflateStream compressionStream = new DeflateStream(compressedDestinationStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        uncompressedSourceStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);
    }
}

public void DecompressData(Stream compressedSourceStream, Stream uncompressedDestinationStream)
{
    using (DeflateStream decompressionStream = new DeflateStream(uncompressedDestinationStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        compressedSourceStream.CopyTo(decompressionStream);
    }
}

using (FileStream sourceStream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\MyDir\MyFile.txt))
using (FileStream destinationStream = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\MyDir\MyCompressedFile.txt.cp"))
{
    CompressData(sourceStream, destinationStream)
}
```

See the [AesCryptoServiceProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider.aspx) for information on how to encrypt data. It shouldn't be hard to modify the example to encrypt a stream instead of a string.

It's also possible to issue certificates to users and perform encryption/decryption based on that but it's more complicated. For that you'll need to look at the [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ztkw6e67).